# Xceed -> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, overflow

I have an application that uses some Xceed libraries and we are starting to deploy it on Windows 7.  The problem is with the WinComboBox object: if I use the scroll wheel on the mouse and scroll down/"past" the bottom of the list *REALLY FAST* (it has to be *fast*, going *slow* or using the keyboard will not trigger this) then I get this error.

```
Unhandled exception occured in ->Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.>>>    
at Xceed.Editors.ComboBoxTextBoxArea.WndProc(Message& m)[0Dh][0Ah]   
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)[0Dh][0Ah]   
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I know what the error means, but I can't figure out where it is occurring or how to pinpoint what is happening.

This only happens with the Windows 7 machines (never had a problem on any XP systems) and is easy to reproduce... it is even reproducible with the Xceed example/demo apps, so that's how I figure the problem is in their code.  Unfortunately I do not have the source for Xceed, and we are two versions behind, but I was hoping that maybe somebody else has already dealt with this or has an idea.  I've tried to override several methods where I thought the error might be, but no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: afraid that this is a (un)known strange issue on x64 bit systems. http://wpf.codeplex.com/workitem/10533 or http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q38759.aspx or http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/discussions/208879

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using a System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox on my Windows 7 64bit OS.  By making the project run in 32bit mode instead of 64bit mode, the problem went away:

Using Visual Studio 2008

1. Right click on startup project and click Properties

2. Click on Build in the left side bar

3. Change the value in Platform target to x86